# Constant speed issue in defining iTween path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I've designed a curved path like the below figure.
[image]

The cube move along the path from the left side to the right side of scene by this line of code:

```
iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash("oncomplete","destroying","orienttopath", true, "path",path,"time",1.6,"easetype",iTween.EaseType.linear,"movetopath",false));
```

the *EaseType* parameter is was selected *linear* and I expect to path the path with a constant velocity, however the speed is reduced when the cube is in the curved path (left side before the midpoint) and then in a straight path it accelerates and catches it up.

I would like to know how can I define a constant speed for entire path.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTween will take the same time going from node 1 to node 2 as it will going from node 2 to node 3. Since your first 2 nodes are close together it will go slowly here and speed up towards the third.

If you get a more uniform distance between your nodes you'll experience a smoother path using *linear easetype*

Comment: Is there any way to use iTween in a way where it ignored node distances and just uses the overall path length?

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an answer, but more of a comment on my research into this issue. It seems the PixelPlacement guy has been [promising a fix for at least 3 years now](http://code.google.com/p/itween/issues/detail?id=98), but nothing is forthcoming. People are having to work around it. I found a reasonable example [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/getting-constant-speed-from-itween-solution-included-c-files-attached.182693/).

Annoying. But it is free. Although I did pay for the examples, which is ultimately very cheap, but still a little frustrating as I'd hoped this would be addressed given the amount of chatter on the internet about it!